# How to render a react component from html string in ReactJS while setting in dangerouslysetinnerHtml?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to load a component dynamically from html string. for example:
I am having a html string like following which is from json.

```
 <div>This is some html content having a component of <Combobox params="option1,option2,option3"/></div>
```

here `<Combobox params="option1,option2,option3"/>` is a React component which i need to render as a HTML combobox with options 1,2 and 3 along with the texts. So, is there any way to do this kind of things in React.

Answer (score 2):

The entire JSX can be parsed to HTML using renderToString method.

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';   

render() {
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<div><Combobox /></div>);
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html}></div>
  );
}
```

Comment: hai vijay above code shows me error beacuse in my json it is a html string with react component name. but here we need to pass it like a raw

Answer (score 2):

To build on [vijayst's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39052003/4500152), if you're using redux/react-redux, and this happens to be a "connected" component, you'll need to import and pass the store along again.

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../redux/store';

render() {
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Provider store={store}><Combobox /></Provider>);
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html}></div>;
}
```